# External config in Spring Boot application within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I want to run this Dockerfile application:

```
FROM java:8-jre
ADD config/ /deploy/
COPY ./meta.std.1.0.1.jar /deploy/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/meta.std.1.0.1.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/deploy/meta.std.1.0.1.jar","metastore","spring.config.location=./config/metadata-server.yml"]
EXPOSE 3011
```

While running, it's not reading the metadata-server.yml values? Is this the correct way?

Comment: what is this metastore. Try with `--spring.config.location=.....`

Comment: I am passing one argument metastore to run my application .After correction ,I am getting Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--spring.config.location=./config/metadata-server.yml" this exception .

Comment: can you show your main springboot class. and also try with   `--spring.config.location=classpath:/config/metadata-server.yml`  or `file:/......`

Comment: this is my spring boot main class ,public static void main( String[] args ) {

  System.setProperty( "spring.config.name" , "metastore-server" );
  System.setProperty( "spring.config.location" , "file://config/" );
  SpringApplication.run( MetastoreServer.class , args );

Answer (score 0):

I think that you put the wrong path of metadata-server.yml

> "spring.config.location=./config/metadata-server.yml"

I think that after:

> ADD config/ /deploy/

the path of metadata-server.yml should be:

> "spring.config.location=/deploy/config/metadata-server.yml"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FROM java:8-jre
ADD config/ /deploy/
COPY ./meta.std.1.0.1.jar /deploy/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/meta.std.1.0.1.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/deploy/meta.std.1.0.1.jar","metastore","--spring.config.location=classpath:file:/deploy/metadata-server.yml"]
EXPOSE 3011
```

**Update:**

Or better try this

```
FROM alpine:edge

VOLUME /tmp

RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && apk --no-cache add openjdk8-jre

ADD config/ /deploy/
COPY ./meta.std.1.0.1.jar /deploy/
ADD /YOUR/CONFIG/metadata-server.yml /deploy/metadata-server.yml

EXPOSE 3011

ENTRYPOINT ["java" ,"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom --spring.config.location=classpath:file:/deploy/metadata-server.yml","-jar","/deploy/meta.std.1.0.1.jar"]
```